# .bat file xcopy file based only on filename which has a timestamp

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file that does the following.

```
xcopy c:\folder\*.* d:\another_folder\.
del *.xml
del *.lst
```

The generated file has a timestamp in its name:

> MY_FILE_11111_08-23-2016_111111.xml

The date time starts after the third `_` formatted as `MM-DD-YYYY_HHMMSS`

How do I write a bat command that will only copy if the filename has today's date?

Comment: Depending on your system date format it could as simple as this: `xcopy c:\folder\*%date:/=-%* d:\another_folder\.`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your efforts! Does the date/time format in the file name comply with the format returned by `date /T` and `time /T` commands?

Answer (score 0):

There is the predefined environment variable `DATE` which holds current local date in format defined by the Windows Region settings. Run in a command prompt window the line

```
echo %DATE%
```

In case of output is `08/23/2016` (MM/DD/YYYY) just each slash must be replaced in the string by a hyphen as [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) suggested already with a one-liner command line.

```
set "FileDate=%DATE:/=-%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "C:\Folder\*%FileDate%*" "D:\Another_Folder\"
```

But current date string must be reformatted if output is for example `Tue, 23/08/2016` (with weekday) or just `23/08/2016` (without weekday) which would be for both date format examples:

```
set "FileDate=%DATE:~-7,2%-%DATE:~-10,2%-%DATE:~-4%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "C:\Folder\*%FileDate%*" "D:\Another_Folder\"
```

How the character replace (first method) respectively concatenation of specific substrings (second method) works is explained in help of command **SET** which can be read by opening a command prompt window and running `set /?` or alternatively `help set`.

If just a single file must be copied, it is most likely enough to use internal command **COPY** of Windows command processor instead of Windows standard console application (external command) `xcopy.exe`. Run in a command prompt window `copy /?` and `xcopy /?` to get displayed the helps for those two copying commands.